# I'm trying to create a leaderboard using Firebase and show the username, highscore, region.

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My goal is to create a leaderboard using Firebase and to show the username, high score and region in a tableview. My current Database looks like this [image]

I have everything under user at the moment. I did it this way so i could increment data for the current user. Unfortunately, by doing it this way, I don't think I can let others see someone elses high score or username.
Is there a solution to this problem using the current node setup, or do I need to change it. And if so can someone give my examples of how the database should look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should separate your user specific data from the leaderboards.

You have your users node in which your user's data under their unique user id.
Then you also can create a leaderboards node and under the same unique user id, your leaderboard specific data. This way you won't have to fetch all the data at once only to know the user specific data.

The connection is the user id, that is the unique id, that your user is going to know, and retrieve his/her data by. The other players can just retrieve the leaderboards node by a query. You should also store some seemingly redundant data, for instance the username which you would both need for the user's node and for the leaderboards.

Don't forget to apply security rules, so the user can only write to his/her data.

Looking like this:

[image]

The authenticated user who knows his/her UID can then listen to his/her own leaderboard score by fetching data on this path: "leaderboards/UID" right.

Other players should just have to use the path: "leaderboards" to fetch every player on the leaderboard. To order them and only fetch the top 10 players you have to use queries.

Use queryOrderedByChild to order your data by highscore
For this you should also add the security rule: ".indexOn": "highscore".

To fetch the top10 players use
queryLimitedToFirst setting it to 10, it will only download the top 10 players.

You should read more about queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: A few things. Can you give my a code example of querying everything after the UID. Because even though this is more efficient, it hasn't addressed the problem I have. I'm not sure query or display a snapshot if I don't have a reference to the UID. I get how to do it for the current user, but how do I view all users and it's nodes.

Comment: Can't give you exact code since I'm not familiar with swift but added edited the answer with some information.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @Durian this isn't right. how are you suppost to query on "score" if you use rootRef.leaderboardRef.queryOrdered(byChild: score). that doesnt work, because score isn't a child of leaderboards, you need to go through every single userId if you're going to take that approach.

Comment: How else would you ever orderByChild if it wasn't a child of Leaderboards. Score is a child of Leaderboards. It is just not it's direct child.

Answer (score 3):

While using JSON the flatter the tree the better it is to

```
HighScore :{
  userID1 : 100,
  userID2 : 103;
  userID3 : 210;
   }, 
Users :{
  userID1 :{...}
  userID2 :{...}
  userID3 :{...}     
 }
```

If you want to add a different relational property to the user, just add another parent node for that particular user and query it.

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("HighScores").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snap) in

        print(Snap.value)

    })
```

**PS:-** You can always play with security rules in firebase , to manipulate the permissions for specific node in the Database to your authenticated users [Docs Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

To append your data in firebase node:-

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("HighScores").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(Snap) in

        if let snapDict = Snap.value as? NSMutableDictionary{

            snapDict.setObject(_yourHighScore, forKey : FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid as NSCopying)
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("HighScores").setValue(snapDict)
        }
    })
```

Comment: But how you can add more players because .set just removes others and adds the most recent one.

Answer (score 1):

You can store everything under user node if you want. And fetch user details by applying sort based on high score. You should also apply limit.

If you are planning to create separate node for user details and score then you must fetch score from the score node and based on user id fetch user detail from user node.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Durian 's answer, the code should look something like this,

```
let leaderboardDB = Database.database().reference().child("leaderboards")
leaderboardDB.queryOrdered(byChild: "score").queryLimited(toFirst: 100).observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                print("Retrieving Data!")
                for child in snapshot.children {
                   print("Do whatever you need to do with the data")
                }
            } else {
                print("DB no data!")
            }
        })
    }
```

You can chain the queryOrder method call with queryLimited method together to retrieve the data. You don't have to be bothered with the userId wrapping your leaderboard datum, the `queryOrdered(byChild: "score")` method will look through everyone's score in the database and order them accordingly.